# jQuery HTML string has changed without any modifications

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with my dynamically created HTML string.

That code is being executed in a loop.

Firstly, I get into the `else` code block.

In the second loop's iteration, I get insode the `if(found.length > 0) {}` code block and in the first line I see that the returned HTML has no closing input's slash `/`. Why ?

```
var newHtml = $('');

if(file.updateWithId !== 0) {
   var found = $(newHtml).find('input.del-file-cb[file-id="' + file.updateWithId + '"]');

   if(found.length > 0) {
       var replaceValue = found.parent().parent().html(); //here I see changed HTML
       found.parent().parent().find('label.label-none:eq(0)').text(file.name);
       found.parent().parent().find('label.label-none:eq(1)').text(file.type);
       rowsAppends = rowsAppends.replace(replaceValue, $(newHtml).html());
       newHtml = $(rowsAppends);
   }
 } else {
     rowsAppends += '<tr><td class="text-left"><label class="label-none">' + file.name + '</label></td><td><label class="label-none">' + file.type + '</label></td><td><input class="del-file-cb" file-id="' + file.file_id + '" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>';
     newHtml = $(rowsAppends);
 }
```

Comment: So the problem is you don't have a closing slash on your input? Are you using HTML5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of the html() method depends on the browser, and may not always match the original source. The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/) say:

> This method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may
>   not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original
>   document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the
>   quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric
>   characters.

For example, there's [at least one report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4509) that Internet Explorer removes the slash from self-closing tags like `<input>`. There's likely nothing you can do about it.